# Extract registers using Modbus RTU protocol

Tags: c#, tcp, ip, modbus

I am new to using the Modbus protocol. I have a media converter device ([USR-W610](https://www.pusr.com/download/WIFI/USR-W610-User-Manual-V1.0.1.01.pdf)), I am testing the connection with the Modbus Poll and Modscan programsto verify that I am getting logs. I have these settings on the device.

[image]

Using TCP protocol and port 502

[image]

[image]

[image]

According to these configurations, I configure the following fields in Modscan

[image]

[image]

I configure the Device Id = 240 and select "03. HOLDING REGISTER" to read the data, but nevertheless I get the following messages "uninitialized" and later "Received Invalid Response TO MODBUS Query" Can someone help me? Any ideas?

Similarly using "Modbus Poll" I get the following messages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused.  You said you are testing to see if you are sending data correctly.  In the picture in RED LETTERS it says "Receive Invalid response to MODBYS Query".  So it looks like you are sending the wrong response.  You just can't send if you are getting a query.  You have to respond to the query.

Comment: @jdweng I'm trying to get records, not sending, for now I just want to read data. I edited the question.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check if the server is sending the data correctly.   Then compare results with the format at Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus. It doesn't look like you have any data so I would change setting "Auto Read Enable".  If you are automatically reading every 1000ms and no data is being transmitted than you will get errors.

Comment: What is the model of the Moxa unit you are using? Have you checked its logs? (many of the Moxa units support a logging utility that can show you the requests/responses passing through them).

Comment: @Brits The version of the moxa that I'm using is USR-W610
How can I access the requests / responses? When I access the administrator panel of IP 10.10. ***. **** from the browser I can't find a log.

Comment: OK - that is a USR IOT device, not a Moxa unit (Moxa is a brand; I'm not aware of another use of the term). Including the device details in your question is usually a good idea; I will post an answer.

Comment: I think you are assuming that Modbus RTU and Modbus TCP is the same protocol over a different media, but this is false. They are two different protocols with different byte sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on the assumption that you have a Modbus RTU device connected to the USR IOT unit via RS232 or RS485 (you did not mention the device in your question). From your screenshot the USR-W610 is running in Transparent mod (the "Data Transfer mode"); from [the manual](https://www.pusr.com/download/WIFI/USR-W610-User-Manual-V1.0.1.01.pdf):

> In this work mode, W610 can make a bidirectional connection between serial side and network side. This connection is transparent transmission. Data from serial device can be received in network, and network data can also be sent to serial device.

So in this mode anything you send through the network port will be sent to the serial port and vice versa (no changes are made). This means that you would need to use [Modbus RTU](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) rather than [Modbus TCP](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf) (the two protocols differ; for example RTU packets include CRC error-checking whereas Modbus TCP packets do not) and also set the baud rate etc somehow (probably via [AT commands](https://www.pusr.com/download/WIFI/USR-W610-AT-Command-Set-V1.0.0.pdf)). Doing this is possible (generally using a [virtual serial port](https://www.pusr.com/support/downloads/usr-vcom-virtual-serial-software) but some utilities support this mode and you can write your own code).

However there is a simpler option; if you change the mode to "ModbusTCP<=>ModbusRTU mode" I believe this will solve your issue; from the manual:

> W610 supports Modbus TCP<=>Modbus RTU mode(doesn’t support Modbus ASCII). User just needs to configure W610 work mode to Modbus TCP<=>Modbus RTU mode and change related parameters (port, remote IP and some other parameters) to correct settings when user wants to use this mode.

So in this mode the W610 acts as a Modbus TCP Server. It accepts commands, sends these on to the device using Modbus RTP and then translates the responses back to Modbus TCP.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, I changed the Modbus TCP <=> Modbus RTU mode and I set the port number to 502, I was able to get registers,