# PyModbus failing to read input registers in RTU Over TCP

Tags: python, tcp, modbus, pymodbus

I tried to read Modbus signal using `pymodbus` but got error
The source is as follows:
There is a MAC address notification function when the server responds to TCP. How can Modbus communication be possible without error?
How do I remove the TCP header part?

[image]

The manual is the address below:
https://www.eztcp.com/en/download/pds_files/an_ezmanager_en.pdf

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer as ModbusFramer
import time

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def run_read_data(ip, port_num, unit_num):
    while True:
        client = ModbusTcpClient(ip, port=port_num, framer=ModbusFramer)
        con = client.connect()
        while con :
            rr = client.read_input_registers(0,10, unit=unit_num)        
            try:
                print(rr,rr.registers)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
  
                time.sleep(2)
                client.close()
                time.sleep(2)
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = "x.x.x.x" 
    port_num = x
    unit_num = 0x1
    run_read_data(ip, port_num,unit_num)
```

and the result is this:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x18 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x72 0x4
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0xe8 0xf9 0x2 0x45 0xf3 0x88 0x1 0x22
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:CRC invalid, discarding header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0xe8 0xf9 0x2 0x45 0xf3 0x88 0x1 0x22
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 24
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x18 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x72 0x4
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0xe9 0x9f 0x2 0x45 0xf3 0xd5 0x1 0x22
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:CRC invalid, discarding header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0xe9 0x9f 0x2 0x45 0xf3 0xd5 0x1 0x22
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 24
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a coding problem at all.  I did a project involving MODBUS over TCP recently and there was no checksum calculation needed,  So there was no possibility of a CRC error, which apparently you are seeing.  According to Wikipedia there are two types of MODBUS on TCP - one involves a checksum and one doesn't.  I think you need to check the documentation for the device and then check the configuration of the PyMODBUS library.

Comment: Please add details of the device you are communicating with; I suspect your issue may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390999/extract-registers-using-modbus-rtu-protocol).

Comment: Thanks for the manual. You mentioned the 'Send MAC Address' setting in your (now deleted) answer; that would need to be turned off (receiving the MAC address is not part of the modbus spec). In your example the `0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa` as ASCII is "0030f9114085" followed by CR/LF so looks like the MAC address (and is causing the issue - the bit after that is what I would expect).

Comment: That's right, the MAC address is attached to the TCP header and it causes a problem. How can I print it without error while using this function

Comment: You would need to add code to retrieve the MAC from the socket yourself (after calling `client.connect()`). Note - you can edit your question (there is no need to create a new, almost identical, question).

Comment: Thank you for answer
I do not know how to change the result value after connection without error

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have that capability yet. I would appreciate it if you can tell me how to reprocess the received data and print it out without errors.

Comment: The [pymodbus source](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/pymodbus/client/sync.py#L238) should provide you with a starting point (how to read from the socket).

Comment: Thank you for answer
Please give me an example source code that tells pymodbus how to start

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me (and, sorry, I'm not going to write this for you). I think will need to code this yourself (if you give it a good try and cannot get it to work then post your code and ask for help in a specific area). Note: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is invalid, you can see that CRC check failed - the problem is with modbusTCP server. Because of that `response` has no atribute `registers` what causes an exception. However, if you want to see what error looks like, you should print `rr` without anything else.

Good way to check if there was an error is to use `isError()` methond:

```
if rr.isError():
    # handle error
else:
    # proceed with response
```

If you're trying to decode message you should use `BinaryPayloadDecoder` as follows:

```
decoder = BinaryPaloadDecoder.fromRegisters(rr.registers)
value = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
```

Full reference [here](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/library/payload.html).

Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by "How do I remove the TCP header part".

Comment: An error occurs because more data is attached to the TCP response part.